# Django validate user input with generic listview filter

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

So I'm making a really simple filter based on a generic listview. I use "GET" to retrieve a user input from a searchfield/ filterfield.

I want to filter my data on "arrival_date", a DateField in models.Delivery. So this filter works but any given number will be compared to the contents of "arrival_date"

What i want to do is validate the user input, it can only contain numbers and the characters "-" or "/". Besides the characters i also want to say the query needs at least four digits to be a valid input.

In a regular form I'd use "clean_arrival_date" to use any validation but I need a push in the right direction to apply the same sort of validation required in this listview...

Thanks for the help,

Kevin

Below; the views.py containing the overriding listview with query_set

```
    #views.py    

    """
    Date selector based on ListView
    """

    from django.views.generic import ListView

    from .models import Delivery

    class DeliveryDateListView(ListView):
        model = Delivery
        template_name = 'data/deliveries_by_date.html

        def get_queryset(self):
            # Fetch the queryset from the parent get_queryset
            queryset = super(DeliveryDateListView, self).get_queryset()

            # Get the data GET parameter
            date = self.request.GET.get("date")
            if date:
                # Return a filtered queryset
                return queryset.filter(arrival_date__icontains=date)
            # Return the base queryset
            return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you pass it via URL please read this [django's url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/)

And then, if you using Ajax in JS:

Just check the input (you can check the event key down or check when submit)

We have many way to do this

Comment: Well, I'd like to use the "Django-way" of validating input, the field will hold a datepicker with jQuery but still, there will be some users who will fill in the field and ignore the datepicker..

Comment: so you have to check it before submit.
User don't pick so you can disable the field, we have many solutions

Comment: Off course we can disable the field, let's say we're not using a datepicker, no js, no ajax, just a plain field to fill in a date... How would you validate by using the build in Django validation?

Comment: Django only run in server. So the data come to Django should be correct. In your case, you want to check it in server, that all... all the form and the thing in FE (client), Django don't care!